# The program works but I'm getting an error Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571) at the bottom cart[1]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

The error happens at if cart[1]
The cart[1] is underlined and I can't deploy the code to Vercel.

Thought it was a stripe problem but I thoroughly checked stripes API and this code make as much sense as I can think of.

here's is the full file. its a .ts extension

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

import Stripe from "stripe";
const stripe = new     Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!, {
  apiVersion: "2020-03-02",
});

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const cartItems = req.body;
      const line_items = validateCartItems(cartItems);
      const subscriptionInCart = isSubscriptionInCart(cartItems);
      const params: Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateParams = {
        mode: subscriptionInCart ? "subscription" : "payment",
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        billing_address_collection: "auto",
        shipping_address_collection: {
          allowed_countries: ["US", "CA"],
        },
        line_items,
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/result?session_id=.   {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/use-shopping-cart`,
      };
      const checkoutSession: Stripe.Checkout.Session =
        await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(params);

      res.status(200).json(checkoutSession);
    } catch (err: any) {
      res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: err.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
}

const validateCartItems = (cartDetails: any) => {
  const validatedItems = [];
  for (const sku in cartDetails) {
    const product = cartDetails[sku];
    const item = {
      price: product.sku,
      quantity: product.quantity,
    };
    validatedItems.push(item);
  }

  return validatedItems;
};

const isSubscriptionInCart = (cartDetails: any) => {
  let subscriptionFound = false;
  for (const cartItem of Object.entries(cartDetails)) {
    if (cartItem[1].recurring) {
      subscriptionFound = true;
    }
  }
  return subscriptionFound;
};
```

Comment: How can the program work if there is an error?

Comment: it works per se, It works locally and executes all the functions. Its an e-commerce, I can create the subscriptions and its documented on my stripe dashboard---thats what I mean by works.

Comment: Figure the complier was complaining about the value type changed the code to: const isSubscriptionInCart = (cartDetails: any) => {
  let subscriptionFound = false;
  let recurring = cartDetails
  try {
    for (const cartItem of Object.entries(cartDetails)) {
      if (cartItem[1]= recurring) {
        subscriptionFound = true;
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  return subscriptionFound;
};

Comment: You should properly type `cartDetails` in both `validateCartItems` and `isSubscriptionInCart` functions to avoid potential issues like this one.

Comment: @juliomalves can you please clarify that?

Comment: Because `cartDetails` is typed as `any`, running `(const cartItem of Object.entries(cartDetails))` means that `cartItem` is typed as `[string, unknown]` which is then causing the issue since TypeScript expects `cartItem[1]` to be `unknown` and doesn't contain the property `recurring`. Properly typing `cartDetails` would solve that - what's the format of `cartDetails`?

Comment: makes perfect. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As @juliomalves mentioned, your `cartDetails` is correctly identifying a type error.

You need to specify a type for `cartDetails` so that `cartItem[1].recurring` is expected to be defined in a way that matches with your use of it.

Something like `const isSubscriptionInCart = (cartDetails: Array<{recurring: boolean}>) => { ...}` or better yet defining your own `type CartItem` and using `Array<CartItem>`

Comment: Thanks! This answer is perfect, defining the types is  definitely cleaner code.